# Disable Tab Pages on Form load and then enable on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have four TabPages in a TabControl and on the form load the first TabPage should be Enable and others should be disable. ( Not Hide, Remove or disable Contents of the TabPages).

The following is the example in which first TabPage is enable and others are disable and their text are also dim

[image]

I am new to C#, Looking for simple and accurate solution in c# 2010

Thanks

Comment: Using a non-standard user interface does little but confuse the user.  Simply not adding disabled tab pages is the unconfusing and simple approach.  Implementing the DrawItem and Selecting events allow you to make it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read you can not disable tabs like that directly. You do have few alternatives.

1. First Alternative. 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/252t3cec.aspx
2. Second alternative is there may be some third party add on that you can install something like this one.

http://dotnetrix.co.uk/controls.htm

But this is for old versions of .Net I believe, you can search to see if anything latest is available.

3 Alternative can be found here. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/985b41c3-a1de-4744-8875-63262d4c2718/